# Prober type for type "char text [100]" in class

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I have the following but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I obviously have the wrong types in the argument definition but I can't figure out what the correct syntax would be.

dto.h

```cpp
...
class Dto
{
    public:
        struct msg
        {
            int id;
            byte type;
            char text[100];
        };

        char* getText();
        void setText(char* text);

    private:
        Dto::msg message;
...
```

dto.cpp

```cpp
...
char* Dto::getText()
{
    return Dto::message.text;
}

void Dto::setText(char* text)
{
    Dto::message.text = text;
}
...
```

When I compile I get:

```
Dto.cpp:85:30: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [100]' Dto::message.text = text;
```

Comment: You probably want to use `strcpy(message.text, text);`

Comment: Or use `std::string`s

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not on Arduino.

Comment: @gre_gor I've used it on Arduino in the past - but every since I discovered that the Arduino STL doesn't do move semantics, I've sort of stopped. It's still safer/easier than using raw `char` arrays i.m.o. Perhaps the Arduino `String` would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to an array.  To copy a C-string to a `char` array, you need `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(Dto::message.text, text);
```

Better yet, use `strncpy` to ensure you don't overflow the buffer:

```
strncpy(Dto::message.text, text, sizeof(Dto::message.text));
Dto::message.text[sizeof(Dto::message.text)-1] = 0;
```

Note that you need to manually add a null byte at the end if the source string is too big, since `strncpy` won't null terminate in that case.